# How to test payment using a test account in PayPal?

Tags: paypal

Good evening. I am implementing a functional payment / deposit via PayPal service. But faced with the problem of testing a payment through your service. On the site: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/, I created a test account, as stated in the documentation. Accordingly, when you pay on your website, me translate the following link: https://www.paypal.com/ru/cgi-bin/merchantpaymentweb?cmd=_flow&SESSION=AzDY0mgc56lEVWAENTHGk2C_6qPANmTQqgxuqinmwZTjuPxIhSLJZ046mbS&dispatch=50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b081984719ecfa9a8ffe80733a1a700ced90ae
on the payment page. But it displays an input error test account data.
Please help me with the payment testing through test account.

Comment: That URL you provided is using the live www.paypal.com instead of sandbox.paypal.com.  Maybe that's your problem..??

Comment: Https://www.sandbox.paypal.com substitutes instead of https: //www.paypal.com

Comment: outputs: We're sorry, but your session has ended. Your account has not been charged. Please go back to the merchant's site and check out again with PayPal.